# Show list menu when leading is pressed

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know how can I achieve this feature.

When the leading of the app bar will be pressed, I must show a menu list.

[image]

I was trying use a Stack at the body of the Scaffold

home_page.dart

```
  body: Stack(
        children: [
          Selectable(show: _showDropDownMenu),
          subPages[currentIndex]
        ],
      ),
```

But the Selectable widget does not overlap the content(in this case to the content of the pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you can design it now

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _currentIdex = 0;
  bool _show = false;
  final pages = [
    Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text("Main Widget"),
      ),
    ),
    Feed(),
    Calu(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _show = !_show;
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.more_horiz,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text("OverlapMenu test"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        children: [
          ///pages must at top level

          Center(
            child: pages[_currentIdex],
          ),

          if (_show)
            Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentIdex = 0;
                        _show = !_show;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        20,
                      ),
                      child: Text("main"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentIdex = 1;
                        _show = !_show;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        20,
                      ),
                      child: Text("feed"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentIdex = 2;
                        _show = !_show;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        20,
                      ),
                      child: Text("calue"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  const Feed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text("Feed"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Calu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text("Calue"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```